# Accessing .gdb?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase

I downloaded a geodatabase with a series of numbers behind the file extension. For example, in my Window's Explorer the file appears as .gdb_15120592. I have attempted to create a new .gdb and move the files into the new .gdb. This allows me to see the shapefiles in ArcCatalog, however, once imported into ArcMap the attribute tables are empty.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if I just ended up with an empty database.

Comment: "This allows me to see the shapefiles in ArcCatalog" Huh? File geodatabase doesn't store shapefiles. If ArcGIS doesn't see it as-is, request a new dataset from the provider.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the contents of a file GDB folder in Windows Explorer should be done sparingly, as the "new" GDB will be corrupted/unreadable if it doesn't have the same structure and schemas as the original - the tables in the GDB are dependent on that, and you'll encounter errors such as what you are seeing with empty tables if this is the case.

Much safer to modify the name of the original GDB you downloaded to remove the "_XXX" number suffix from the end.  You should then be able to access the data within the GDB without issue.  Of course, it is possible that the data itself is bad, in which case you should reach out to the source provider.